# Current coordinates of a tableViewCell swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation, cgrect, cgpoint

fellows!

I'm trying to make an animation of an image in my tableViewCell. My intent is to get an imageView that is in a tableViewCell, add it to exactly the same place in a view, and then use scale animation. Currently, my code looks as below, however, I need to find a cell center point in every period of time (after scrolling too), that I can add image view exactly in the same place. The value of cellRect.origin.y constantly increases, whereas I need it to be exactly center.y point of my tableView cell.
Could you please tell me where my mistake is?

Thank you in advanse!

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.animateImageView = { [weak self]
        guard let self = self else { return }
        tableView.layoutSubviews()
        var cellRect = self.view.convert(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath), to: self.tableView)
        cellRect.origin.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.midX - (cell.photoImageView.frame.width / 2)
        cellRect.origin.y = cellRect.origin.y + (cell.photoImageView.frame.height / 2)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            
        } completion: { isFinished in
            
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: try move code "var cellRect = self.view.convert(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath), to: self.tableView)" before "cell.animateImageView "

Comment: No, it works in the same way, but thank you for your reply.

Comment: I am a little confused with this comment: `I need to find a cell center point in every period of time (after scrolling too), that I can add image view exactly in the same place.` - I understand that as soon the user tap, you want an image to be recreated at the exact same position on the screen but outside the cell. However, what should happen exactly when it scrolls ? Should it move, should it stay fixed - If you can add some example or idea of your final goal, that will be helpful (atleast to me)

Comment: Hi, @ShawnFrank. My intent is to bring imageView from my cell to the front in exactly that place where it is now on-screen (including after-scroll). Then, I want to animate it to screen-size, and on completion, I'll push a new viewController. Hope that I explained clearly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is your goal

1. you tap on a UITableViewCell which has an imageView
2. You want to create a new image view with the same image in the same position as the image in the cell you tapped
3. Then from this position you will make this image full screen with animation
4. You want to do something after the animation has completed

If yes, there here are my thoughts

I feel this line has the first issue:

```
var cellRect 
   = self.view.convert(tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath),
                       to: self.tableView)
```

Let's take a look at the convert function in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert)

> Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of another view.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **rect**
>
> *A rectangle specified in the local coordinate system
> (bounds) of the receiver.*
>
> **view**
>
> *The view that is the target of the conversion operation. If view
> is nil, this method instead converts to window base coordinates.
> Otherwise, both view and the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow
> object.*

The `receiver` here is your `cell's image view` which you want to recreate so you should not call `self.view.convert`, it should be `cell.photoImageView.convert`

The `rect` parameter is the bounds of your tapped cell's image view and the `to` parameter is `self.view` as you want to convert the image view's coordinates in the cell to the coordinates in the main view of the view controller.

Beyond that I am not sure of the purpose of these as you will get the frame from the above function so I removed them but you can add it back if it makes sense to your application.

```
cellRect.origin.x 
  = UIScreen.main.bounds.midX - (cell.photoImageView.frame.width / 2)

cellRect.origin.y 
  = cellRect.origin.y + (cell.photoImageView.frame.height / 2)
```

So this is how I changed the function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    // Retrieved the actual cell that was tapped
    // same as what you did
    let cell
        = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    
    // Here I made a change based on my explanation above
    let cellRect =
        cell.photoImageView.convert(cell.photoImageView.bounds,
                               to: view)
    
    // I created a blue view just for demo
    let aView = UIView(frame: cellRect)
    aView.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(aView)
}
```

If you end it here, you will get this result

[image: Get coordinates of subview UIImageView imageview inside table view cell UITableViewCell UITableView]

The blue view added perfectly where we want it

Now to complete the rest with animation is quite simple after we accomplished the tricky part and here is the full function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    // Retrieved the actual cell that was tapped
    let cell
        = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    
    // Here I made a change based on my explanation above
    let cellRect =
        cell.photoImageView.convert(cell.photoImageView.bounds,
                               to: view)
    
    let animateImageView = UIImageView(frame: cellRect)
    animateImageView.image = cell.photoImageView.image
    animateImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(animateImageView)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0)
    { [weak self] in

        if let strongSelf = self
        {
            animateImageView.frame = strongSelf.view.bounds
        }

    } completion: { (success) in

        if success
        {
            // animation completed, do what you want
            // like push your VC
        }
    }
}
```

The end result I believe is what you want

[image: Animate subview with coordinates of subview UIImageView from table view cell UITableViewCell UITableView]

I hope this helps you get you closer to your desired result

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation! This approach does everything that I need.